# The Wemos D1 R2 board cannont connect to wifi for longer than 10 seconds

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to connect my Wemos D1 R2 to the wifi in my house. It connects and shows only the MAC address of the board but no IP is displayed on the list of the connected device on the router. The serial monitor also doesn't print anything but the dots.

I expected the serial monitor to print my IP address and the Wemos to stay connected to the internet

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char *ssid = "SSID";
const char *password = "Pass";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  delay(3000);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.println(password);

  // ---------------This was the magic WiFi reconnect fix for me
  WiFi.persistent(false);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF); // this is a temporary line, to be removed      after SDK
                       // update to 1.5.4
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  // ---------------END - WiFi reconnect fix

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: Is the string inside `ssid` and `pass` correct for your own wifi connection?

Comment: Yes, everything is correct. It connects and disconnect in less than  10 seconds